# Error when substituting part of curl command with variable

Tags: shell-script, quoting, curl, whitespace

I'm writing a script where I am running curl commands several times. The use of the curl command varies throughout the script and I would like to save myself time (in the future when I have to debug the script) by using a variable to substitute a part of of the command that would be reused several times.

Example of a script that uses curl command `curl -g -x "" -k` several times, but differently

```
# Usage 1
curl -g -x "" -k http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah

# Usage 2
curl -g -x "" -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{'Username':'sally','Password':'password'}" http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blahblah
```

I would like to rewrite the above script using a variable for `curl -g -x "" -k`

```
# Snippet of curl command that will be used several times in script
curl_command="curl -g -x \"\" -k"

# Usage 1
$curl_command http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah

# Usage 2
$curl_command -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{'Username':'sally','Password':'password'}" http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blahblah
```

Running the rewritten script results in an error:

```
curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy: ""; Name or service not known
```

For Usage 1, it appears to be executing`curl -g -x '""' -k http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah`, resulting in the error shown above. I've tried assigning `curl_command="curl -g -x '' -k"` and wrapping the variable in curly braces {} in the execution, but I get similar error. How can this be written to work?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your problem is [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

When you write `$curl_command` outside quotes, this takes the value of the `curl_command` variable and splits it into separate words at each whitespace sequence. (And then each word is interpreted as a wildcard pattern and replaced by the list of matching file names if there are matching file names, but in your case there are no wildcards so this step doesn't change anything.)

Quotes are part of the shell syntax. They aren't affected by the expansion of unquoted variables. So the command `$curl_command` executes `curl` with the arguments `-g`, `-x`, `""` and `-k`.

You're trying to stuff a list of strings (command arguments) into a string. That doesn't work well. Nothing will get you an empty word, in fact.

The robust solution is to use a variable of type *list of strings* to store the list of strings. That's called an array in the shell. Bash, ksh and zsh support arrays:

```
curl_command=(curl -g -x "" -k)
…
"${curl_command[@]}" http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah
```

The variable `curl_command` contains a 5-element array, whose elements are `curl`, `-g`, `-x`, an empty string and `-k`.

If you need a plain sh script, you can use the positional parameters, assuming you don't need them for anything else.

```
set -- curl -g -x "" -k
…
"$@" http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah
```

Another possibility would be to use a function to encapsulate the code that you want to use multiple times.

```
curl_command () {
  curl -g -x "" -k "$@"
}
…
curl_command http://www.example.com/rest/v1/blah
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried your first and third suggestions; the last one works.  The first suggestion did not work because it doesn't register `""` as a the third element and instead takes `-k` as the third element. The second one, wouldn't have helped me achieve my objective so I didn't try that one. Sorry for not following up sooner.